# SQL Union All for three Ignite caches

Tags: java, sql, union, ignite, gridgain

I have three Ignite caches and I want to query these three caches at same time. I have tried this method.

```
public static final String EVENT_VIEW_RESERVED_EVENT_CACHE = "event_view_reserved_event_mc_%d";
public static final String UNCONFIRMED_NON_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE = "unconfirmed_event_mc_%d";
public static final String UNCONFIRMED_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE = "unconfirmed_event_urgent_mc_%d";
IgniteCache<String, Annotations> annotationsCache = ignite.cache(String.format(ANNOTATION_CACHE, orderId));
IgniteCache<String, ConfirmedEvent> confirmedEventCache = ignite.cache(String.format(CONFIRMED_EVENT_CACHE, mcId));
IgniteCache<String, UnconfirmedEvent> unconfirmedEventCache = ignite.cache(String.format(UNCONFIRMED_NON_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId));
        IgniteCache<String, UnconfirmedEvent> unconfirmedUrgentEventCache = ignite.cache(String.format(UNCONFIRMED_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId));

EVENT_GET_RHYTHM_BY_ID = "Select timestamp from ConfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s UNION ALL " +
                    "Select timestamp from " + String.format(UNCONFIRMED_NON_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId) + ".UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s " +
                    "Select timestamp from " + String.format(UNCONFIRMED_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId) + ".UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s " + " order by startTime";
sql_Afib = new SqlFieldsQuery(String.format(EVENT_GET_RHYTHM_BY_ID, AnnotationConverter.StringToRhythmValue(AFIB), AnnotationConverter.StringToRhythmValue(AFIB),
                            AnnotationConverter.StringToRhythmValue(AFIB))).setArgs(orderId, endTimestamp, startTimestamp,
                            orderId, endTimestamp, startTimestamp, orderId, endTimestamp, startTimestamp);
List<Long> EventsEndTime = new ArrayList<>();

                try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = confirmedEventCache.query(sql_Afib)) {
                    for (List<?> row : cursor) {
                        
                        EventsEndTime.add(row.get(0));
                        
                    }
                }
```

In simple my sql query is this.

```
private static final String sql = "select timestamp from ClassName1 UNION ALL select timestamp from table2.ClassName2 UNION ALL select timestamp from table3.ClassName3"; SqlFieldsQuery sqlQ = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql); try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache1.query(sqlQ)) { ....
```

But I am getting this error.

```
CacheException: Failed to parse query. Schema "UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_MC_79" not found; SQL statement:
Select _val from ConfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7 UNION ALL Select _val from unconfirmed_event_mc_79.UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7 Select _val from unconfirmed_event_urgent_mc_79.UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7  order by startTime [90079-199]
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query. Schema "UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_MC_79" not found; SQL statement:
Select _val from ConfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7 UNION ALL Select _val from unconfirmed_event_mc_79.UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7 Select _val from unconfirmed_event_urgent_mc_79.UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = 7  order by startTime [90079-199]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:828)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.query(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:761)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:385)
```

What would be the appropriate way to union three caches from a single sql query? and how to pass the arguments for that query?

Comment: Can you show how do you create these caches?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you are trying to query a table using an invalid schema: `Schema "UNCONFIRMED_EVENT_MC_79" not found;` and it's not about `UNION ALL` operation.

It looks like you have your tables defined in a different cache. Try to do the following: break this union into 3 parts and check them individually. Check this query in particular:

```
"Select timestamp from " + String.format(UNCONFIRMED_NON_URGENT_EVENT_CACHE,mcId) + ".UnconfirmedEvent where orderId = ? and startTime < ? and endTime > ? and type = %s "
```

Comment: I am using three separate caches. confirmedEventCache, unconfirmedEventCache and unconfirmedUrgentEventCache are the three caches. But column names are same in all three caches.